# Replacing a single fragment with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I have one activity (Navigation Controller) that controls multiple fragments. The initial screen the user sees is a single fragment placed into one container. When I click a button to a different fragment I need to add the first fragment to the backstack and add the two new fragments to different containers than the first one. The two fragments are a map fragment on top and a profile details fragment on the bottom Is this even possible?

The code is below.

Navigation Controller Home Fragment (this is the main screen when the app starts):

```
public void home(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        CurrentFriendsFragment firstFragment = new CurrentFriendsFragment();
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        fragmentTransaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, "firstFragment")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Navigation Controller Profile Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onProfileButtonClicked() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState1 != null) {
            return;
        }

        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        fragmentTransaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_up, R.animator.slide_out_up, R.animator.slide_in_down, R.animator.slide_out_down)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_bottom_large, profileFragment)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_top_small, mapFragment)
                .commit();

    }
}
```

And here is the main activities xml file. Note the three different containers. "fragment_container" for full screen fragments, and "fragment_container_top_small", "fragment_container_bottom_large" for multiple fragments on one page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.parse.starter.ViewControllers.NavigationController"
    android:background="@color/palette_darkwhite">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation_navbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_top_small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_bottom_large"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation_navbar">
        </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_popup"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/palette_lightwhite">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/collpaseup" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp">


                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_picture_navbar"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail2"
                android:textColor="@color/palette_primarycolor"
                android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail2"
                android:textColor="@color/palette_primarycolor"
                android:id="@+id/locationLabel"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just host two fragments in another (new) activity?

Comment: It may be, but the whole point of this application is to only use a single activity with multiple fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Have 3 containers and use View.GONE to make the 1st disappear and then View.VISIBLE to make the other 2 appear.

Comment: Whilst doing a similar thing I just constructed my own stack using an ArrayList of fragments.(Actually, not fragments themselves  but an integer telling which fragment to use). You have full control then, just push and pop or manipulate which fragments are displayed yourself.

Comment: Mark Sheekey, could you post an example to help some other people with this problem?